Websocket {"type":7,"allowReconnect":true} Issue with Neoload
While trying to script websockets in Neoload. I have opened a websocket channel and then sent a synchronous wss request to server and expecting a desired response from server in about 1 minute. But after 30 seconds or so I Recieve Type 7 mesage as below and neoload is stuck and doesnt proceed to further steps. 
{"type":6}  
{"type":6}  
{"type":6}  
..  
..  
{"type":7,"allowReconnect":true} 

Is there a way to automatically reconnect or stop the call and send request again. I have tried increasing the
timeout of websocket request using  websocket.client.max.idle.timeout=60000
But it did not help update the timeout.
Has Anyone faced this issue before. Please help.
